# Prevent div shifting on vertical scrollbar appear/disappear but not window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This might be a bit of a strange question... I was wondering if there was anyway to have a div (or any element really) scale normally to window resizes but ignore the appearance/disappearance of the scrollbar? As content is dynamically generated on the page there is a pop out pop in of the scrollbar that shifts content for a second before popping back into place.

It would be nice if this given div could ignored the appearance/disappearance of the scrollbar to keep its child placement and only respond to the window resize.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think IE is the only browser that supports a scrollbar that overlays content. For other browsers I think you'll have to go the custom scrollbar route.

Comment: @hungerstar, using [`-webkit-scrollbar`](https://css-tricks.com/examples/WebKitScrollbars/)

Comment: @TricksfortheWeb interesting, but not really a cross browser solution.

Comment: Why is this tagged ‘java’?  Did you mean javascript?

Comment: @VGR good catch, I did mean Javascript. Fixed the tag!

Answer (score 0):

`overflow: hidden;` will prevent scrollbars from appearing, even if a narrow window causes your element to resize/clip content.

Or, for just horizontal/vertical scrollbars:

`overflow-x: hidden;` turns off just the horizontal scroll.

`overflow-y: hidden;` turns off just the vertical scroll.

---

Other options:

`overflow: auto;` will show scrollbars only when needed (when the window becomes narrow)

`overflow: scroll;` will keep the scrollbar UI there even when scrollbars aren't present (even if the window is wide).

`overflow: visible;` is the default for `overflow` on most elements, it doesn't clip content at all when narrowed, so there are no scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but here is one solution to it anyway.

```css
.element {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

This solution is not ideal because it will keep the scrollbar present even when there is no content but it will prevent it from snapping in and out of view when the content grows past its containers height.  I use this on the `body` element for situations when content is dynamically loaded and appears to flash to the side once it appears.

I also prefer this to plain `overflow: scroll` because it doesn't add an unnecessary scrollbar to the bottom of the container as this isn't usually the problem.